# jQuery conflicting with another jQuery

Tags: jquery, conflict

I've got a curious case in which I believe two jQuery plugins are conflicting with each other: On one hand I've got a [ddsmoothmenu][1] that has worked fine until I've installed the (WP plugin) Revolution slider plugin. After I've installed it, the menu stopped working. The plugin has a no-conflict mode that once on, resolve the issue with the menu but other jQuery effects from other files/plugins stop working. One solution would be to replace the menu, but I really like it and would rather not (unless strictly necessary).

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Update: 
here's the menu jQuery:

```
var ddsmoothmenu={

//Specify full URL to down and right arrow images (23 is padding-right added to top level LIs with drop downs):
arrowimages: {down:['downarrowclass', 'down.gif', 11], right:['rightarrowclass', 'down.gif']},
transition: {overtime:300, outtime:300}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds
shadow: {enable:false, offsetx:5, offsety:5}, //enable shadow?
showhidedelay: {showdelay: 100, hidedelay: 200}, //set delay in milliseconds before sub menus appear and disappear, respectively

detectwebkit: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("applewebkit")!=-1, //detect WebKit browsers (Safari, Chrome etc)
detectie6: document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
css3support: window.msPerformance || (!document.all && document.querySelector), //detect browsers that support CSS3 box shadows (ie9+ or FF3.5+, Safari3+, Chrome etc)
ismobile:navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i) != null,     //boolean check for popular mobile browsers

getajaxmenu:function($, setting){ //function to fetch external page containing the panel DIVs
var $menucontainer=$('#'+setting.contentsource[0]) //reference empty div on page that will hold menu
$menucontainer.html("Loading Menu...")
$.ajax({
    url: setting.contentsource[1], //path to external menu file
    async: true,
    error:function(ajaxrequest){
        $menucontainer.html('Error fetching content. Server Response: '+ajaxrequest.responseText)
    },
    success:function(content){
        $menucontainer.html(content)
        ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
    }
})
```

},

```
buildmenu:function($, setting){
var smoothmenu=ddsmoothmenu
var $mainmenu=$("#"+setting.mainmenuid+">ul") //reference main menu UL
$mainmenu.parent().get(0).className=setting.classname || "ddsmoothmenu"
var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
$headers.hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).children('a:eq(0)').addClass('selected')
    },
    function(e){
        $(this).children('a:eq(0)').removeClass('selected')
    }
)
$headers.each(function(i){ //loop through each LI header
    var $curobj=$(this).css({zIndex: 100-i}) //reference current LI header
    var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)').css({display:'block'})
    $subul.data('timers', {})
    this._dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, subulw:$subul.outerWidth(), subulh:$subul.outerHeight()}
    this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false //is top level header?
    $subul.css({top:this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0})
    $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader? {paddingRight: smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[2]} : {}).append( //add arrow images
        '<img src="'+ (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[1] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[1])
        +'" class="' + (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[0] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[0])
        + '" style="border:0;" />'
    )
    if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){ //if shadows enabled and browser doesn't support CSS3 box shadows
        this._shadowoffset={x:(this.istopheader?$subul.offset().left+smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : this._dimensions.w), y:(this.istopheader? $subul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : $curobj.position().top)} //store this shadow's offsets
        if (this.istopheader)
            $parentshadow=$(document.body)
        else{
            var $parentLi=$curobj.parents("li:eq(0)")
            $parentshadow=$parentLi.get(0).$shadow
        }
        this.$shadow=$('<div class="ddshadow'+(this.istopheader? ' toplevelshadow' : '')+'"></div>').prependTo($parentshadow).css({left:this._shadowoffset.x+'px', top:this._shadowoffset.y+'px'})  //insert shadow DIV and set it to parent node for the next shadow div
    }
    $curobj.hover(
        function(e){
            var $targetul=$subul //reference UL to reveal
            var header=$curobj.get(0) //reference header LI as DOM object
            clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').hidetimer)
            $targetul.data('timers').showtimer=setTimeout(function(){
                header._offsets={left:$curobj.offset().left, top:$curobj.offset().top}
                var menuleft=header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? 0 : header._dimensions.w
                menuleft=(header._offsets.left+menuleft+header._dimensions.subulw>$(window).width())? (header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? -header._dimensions.subulw+header._dimensions.w : -header._dimensions.w) : menuleft //calculate this sub menu's offsets from its parent
                if ($targetul.queue().length<=1){ //if 1 or less queued animations
                    $targetul.css({left:menuleft+"px", width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px'}).animate({height:'show',opacity:'show'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
                    if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){
                        var shadowleft=header.istopheader? $targetul.offset().left+ddsmoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : menuleft
                        var shadowtop=header.istopheader?$targetul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : header._shadowoffset.y
                        if (!header.istopheader && ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, restore shadow's opacity to full
                            header.$shadow.css({opacity:1})
                        }
                        header.$shadow.css({overflow:'', width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px', left:shadowleft+'px', top:shadowtop+'px'}).animate({height:header._dimensions.subulh+'px'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
                    }
                }
            }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.showdelay)
        },
        function(e){
            var $targetul=$subul
            var header=$curobj.get(0)
            clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').showtimer)
            $targetul.data('timers').hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){
                $targetul.animate({height:'hide', opacity:'hide'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
                if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && !smoothmenu.css3support){
                    if (ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, set first child shadow's opacity to 0, as "overflow:hidden" doesn't work in them
                        header.$shadow.children('div:eq(0)').css({opacity:0})
                    }
                    header.$shadow.css({overflow:'hidden'}).animate({height:0}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
                }
            }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.hidedelay)
        }
    ) //end hover
}) //end $headers.each()
if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable && smoothmenu.css3support){ //if shadows enabled and browser supports CSS3 shadows
    var $toplevelul=$('#'+setting.mainmenuid+' ul li ul')
    var css3shadow=parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx)+"px "+parseInt(smoothmenu.shadow.offsety)+"px 5px #aaa" //construct CSS3 box-shadow value
    var shadowprop=["boxShadow", "MozBoxShadow", "WebkitBoxShadow", "MsBoxShadow"] //possible vendor specific CSS3 shadow properties
    for (var i=0; i<shadowprop.length; i++){
        $toplevelul.css(shadowprop[i], css3shadow)
    }
}
$mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'})
```

},

```
init:function(setting){
if (typeof setting.customtheme=="object" && setting.customtheme.length==2){ //override default menu colors (default/hover) with custom set?
    var mainmenuid='#'+setting.mainmenuid
    var mainselector=(setting.orientation=="v")? mainmenuid : mainmenuid+', '+mainmenuid
    document.write('<style type="text/css">\n'
        +mainselector+' ul li a {background:'+setting.customtheme[0]+';}\n'
        +mainmenuid+' ul li a:hover {background:'+setting.customtheme[1]+';}\n'
    +'</style>')
}
this.shadow.enable=(document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest)? false : this.shadow.enable //in IE6, always disable shadow
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //ajax menu?
    if (typeof setting.contentsource=="object"){ //if external ajax menu
        ddsmoothmenu.getajaxmenu($, setting)
    }
    else{ //else if markup menu
        ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting)
    }
})
```

}

```
} //end ddsmoothmenu variable​​
```

And no, I'm not loading more than one version of jQuery. I'm loading all jQuery through register and enqueue script within WordPress (sorry if I wasn't clear before, this is a WordPress site).

The code for the WordPress Revolution Slider is a premium plugins, so I'm not sure I'm allowed to post it here. If anyone could help me clarify that I'd be more than happy to add as well

Update 2: After additional tests, the conflicting jQuery files are these two (the oner above and this one):

```
(function($) {
var aux     = {
        // navigates left / right
        navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

            var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                factor      = 1,
                idxClicked  = 0;

            if( cache.expanded ) {
                scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
                idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
            }

            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }

            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }                       
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                });
            });

        },
        // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
        openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
            cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
            // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
            cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
            $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
                left    : cache.itemW + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = true;

                aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
            });

        },
        // opens all the items
        openItems   : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        left    : cache.itemW + 'px',
                        width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px'
                    });

                    // hide more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, false );
                }
            });
        },
        // show / hide the item's more button
        toggleMore  : function( $item, show ) {
            ( show ) ? $item.find('a.ca-more').show() : $item.find('a.ca-more').hide(); 
        },
        // close all the items
        // the current one is animated
        closeItems  : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                width   : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = false;
            });

            // show more link
            aux.toggleMore( $openedItem, true );

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        width   : '0px'
                    })
                    .end()
                    .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
                    .show();

                    // show more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, true );
                }
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0                  : return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
            }
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing    : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                    itemSpeed       : 500,          // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                    itemEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                    scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache           = {};

                    // save the with of one item    
                    cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                    // save the number of total items
                    cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                    // add navigation buttons
                    if( cache.totalItems > 3 )  
                        $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 

                    // control the scroll value
                    if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                        settings.scroll = 1;
                    else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                        settings.scroll = 3;    

                    var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                        $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute 
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position    : 'absolute',
                            left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                    });

                    // click to open the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        $(this).hide();
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // click to close the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        return false;
                    });

                    // navigate left
                    $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // navigate right
                    $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        else {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading two separate versions of jQuery?  You will need to show us more of your code for us to have any idea what is going on.

Comment: Also, post your code within the OP, otherwise, when you solve this problem, there will be nothing for future readers to see.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery plugin usually looks like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Try to rename myPlugin to another one. Can be both plugins use other similar plugins but different versions of the ? You can find them, and rename one of the duplicates, but you will need to disable update of changed WordPress  plugin

Comment: Please refrain from blindly guessing.  Until the OP posts more code or a demo link, nobody could possibly have an legitimate answer.

Comment: Do not you find it strange that the only answer here at the moment? Question is described generically. That, and my answer is generically to, but my answer is real, and give the right direction

Comment: It's very strange that there's even one answer on such a poor question.

Comment: I've updated my question and have added the code. Hope that makes it clearer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: try to comment cone after /* TABS --------------------------------- */
/* Remove if you don't need :) */, then check. If don't help, comment another block and test it

Comment: I've removed the TABS, other elements and everything else in that file and the menu still didn't work, I've started checking other files and found the two that are conflicting. I just don't know how to resolve it... Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like I won't have much choice... so annoying though. Thanks again :)